# Redirecting single URL with Nginx - not working

Tags: redirects, server, nginx

I have been trying to redirect several single URLs to their new locations using Nginx. The URLs are from Blogger and are in the format: `http://domain.com/yyyy/mm/slug`.

For example, I have this: `http://example.com/2013/04/chartjs-javascript-library-for-easy.html`

I am using this Nginx rewrite to redirect it, but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
server {
     location ~ /([2012-2013]+)/.*/chartjs-javascript-library-for-easy.html {
                return 301 http://$server_name/resource/chart-js;
     }
}
```

I place this in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.conf` which is loaded inside `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Can anybody tell me why it doesn't work? It was working sometime back. Am I messing up my regex?

**EDIT:**

For some reason, location `/test` redirects ok, but location `/test/html` doesn't. Any idea why?

Comment: "`/test` redirects ok, but location `/test/html` doesn't" - is this a problem with ordering? Generally (regardless of platform), more specific rules should appear higher in the execution order.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `[2012-2013]` doesn't mean what you think it does :) `[]` is a *character* class, not a number class :)

Try `location ~ ^/201[23]/.*/chartjs-javascript-library-for-easy.html`